# onSubmit the browser shows whiteable error page. On component render nothing is happening by calling the same endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot

i'm facing a really strange behaviour here. When the page is rendering a submit button is appearing and by clicking it i'm navigating to a whiteable error page. I want to navigate to the whiteable page when i mount the component so i edit my code to call the endpoint that is calling when i click the submit button. In my network the request is exactly the same but i'm not navigating to the whiteable error page. Why is this happening? Here is my code:

```
class Auth3DPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleSubmit();
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    // event.preventDefault();
  }

  onLoadEvent() {
    document.threedfrom.submit();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.errorOn3D) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Link to="dev.travel12.gr:8081/index.html/#/booking/failed">
            Continue
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <body onLoad={() => this.onLoadEvent()}>
        <form name="threedfrom"
              action={this.props.acsUrl}
              method="POST">
        <textarea
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
          name="PaReq"
          value={this.props.pareqMessage}
        />
          <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl"
                 value="http://dev.travel12.gr:8081/payment/authentication/capture" />
          <input type="hidden" name="MD"
                 value={this.props.reservationCode}/>
          <noscript>
            <p align="center" className="main">Testing</p>
            <p align="center" className="main">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </p>
          </noscript>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
          <button type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
      </body>
    );
  }
}
```

when i click the button the response is this:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 
Remote Address: 138.201.6.171:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Allow: GET, HEAD
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 339
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 13 Jun 2018 20:17:57 GMT
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 91
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: http://localhost:3000/
Origin: http://localhost:3000/
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
PaReq: 
TermUrl: http://dev.travel12.gr:8081/payment/authentication/capture
MD:
```

and i'm navigating to whiteable error page
by editing my code so as to call this endpoint the response is exactly the same

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code: 405 
    Remote Address: 138.201.6.171:80
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
    Allow: GET, HEAD
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Language: en-US
    Content-Length: 339
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
    Date: Wed, 13 Jun 2018 20:17:57 GMT
    Server: nginx/1.12.2
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 91
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Host: http://localhost:3000/
    Origin: http://localhost:3000/
    Referer:http://localhost:3000/
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
    PaReq: 
    TermUrl: http://dev.travel12.gr:8081/payment/authentication/capture
    MD:
```

by im not forced to the whiteable error page. Any help please? i'm stuck for days at it

My validation handler is this:

```
package mainServer.web;

import mainServer.errors.ErrorMessageType;
import mainServer.errors.ErrorResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationHandlerController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("messageSource")
    private MessageSource msgSource;

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<ErrorResponse> processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<FieldError> error = result.getFieldErrors();

        return processFieldError(error);
    }

    private List<ErrorResponse> processFieldError(final List<FieldError> errors) {
        List<ErrorResponse> errorResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (! errors.isEmpty()) {
            for (FieldError error : errors){
                Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
                String msg = msgSource.getMessage(error.getDefaultMessage(), null, currentLocale);
                errorResponseList.add(new ErrorResponse(ErrorMessageType.ERROR, msg));
            }
        }
        return errorResponseList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? What url are you redirected to? Do you have some custom error handling setup?

Comment: i have the same that error localhost:3000 not found. See my validation handler in my update code

Comment: Can you paste the error as well? And is that JS code for the auth handler? I don't understand that, sorry.

Comment: The error is this Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jun 13 23:23:55 EEST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available <html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Wed Jun 13 23:23:55 EEST 2018</div><div>There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).</div><div>No message available</div></body></html>

Comment: Well there is a big clue for ya: `This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.` Sounds like you need a route to handle `/error`

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with `spring-boot`, which I am not familiar with. Check out their docs for whitelabel error page: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-actuator.html

Comment: I know. the problem is that when i'm clicking the submit button and call the endpoint this page is shown.  By editing by code i call this endpoint onMount of the component with the exact same endpoint but im not seen the error page

Comment: What are you seeing?

Comment: https://www.google.gr/search?q=whitelabel+error+page&rlz=1C1GGRV_enIT760IT760&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuu_KjwNHbAhVBxRQKHQjWAIEQ_AUICigB&biw=1519&bih=734#imgrc=r1k6bFbi13MVpM:

Comment: I thought you said you didn't see that page?

Comment: No im seeing the page when i submit. When i render the page by calling the same endpoint when submitting i'm not seeing the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173102/discussion-between-chase-deanda-and-user7334203).